# i18next - plural form incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization, i18next

Question, I'm using i18next and all is well, except for plural translations.

Plural translations work great for some languages, but not for others.

For example, Croatian doesn't work. I added some log statements and saw that instead of using the translation key "name_plural" it uses "name_plural_5"..

It has something to do with this piece of code:

```
        var pluralKey = ns + o.nsseparator + key + o.pluralSuffix;
        var pluralExtension = pluralExtensions.get(lngs[0], options.count);
        if (pluralExtension >= 0) {
            pluralKey = pluralKey + '_' + pluralExtension;
        } else if (pluralExtension === 1) {
            pluralKey = ns + o.nsseparator + key; // singular
        }
```

Which references this pluralExtension:

```
            "hr": {
            "name": "Croatian",
            "numbers": [
                1,
                2,
                5
            ],
            "plurals": function(n) {
                return Number(n % 10 == 1 && n % 100 != 11 ? 0 : n % 10 >= 2 && n % 10 <= 4 && (n % 100 < 10 || n % 100 >= 20) ? 1 : 2);
            }
        },
```

For reference, English looks like this:

```
        "en": {
            "name": "English",
            "numbers": [
                1,
                2
            ],
            "plurals": function(n) {
                return Number(n != 1);
            }
        },
```

Now can anyone tell me what this means? Do I need to supply multiple plural translations for this language, and why?

http://i18next.com

Comment: Have you tried using [l10ns](http://l10ns.org)? It handles your plurals with ICU's plural format. Which is much simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has been answered on GitHub by *jamuhl* (creator of i18next):

> Not every language has just one plural for, eg. arabic has over 6.
>
> Plural definitions are taken from: http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/l10n/pluralforms
>
> For that language defining plurals need additional number, see sample: https://github.com/jamuhl/i18next/blob/master/spec/translate/translate.plurals.spec.js#L96

--> *https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/292*